# How to Use win32com in python to format columns value

Tags: python, excel, csv, win32com

I have the following python code to open an excel file and save it as csv but the problem is in the excel file I have some values in some column like this : 0100 and after saving the file as csv the value becomes 100.

```
    xl = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.visible = False
    xl.Interactive = False
    
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path, ReadOnly=1)
    wb.SaveAs(
        Filename="name.csv",
        FileFormat="6",
    )
    wb.Close(True)
    xl.Quit()
```

is there a way to save the file and preserve the format or to change the column format to text

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the csv file in a text editor like notepad. The value will be 0100. The problem is only in excel, where it formats the number before opening any file. The original content of your csv will be 0100. Only when opened in excel, it will show 100.